# Preference selection always staying default

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I am having a small problem, every time i try to change the preferences in my program they never change in the activity, they just stay at what the default is.

```
public class Reciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
boolean smsOn = false;
    String smsColor = new String ("Green");
    Uri smsSound;
    String smsVibrate = new String ("Normal");

    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(arg0);

     smsOn = pref.getBoolean(Preferences."PREF_SMS_ON", false);
     smsColor = pref.getString(Preferences.SMS_PREF_COLOR, "Green");
     smsSound = Uri.parse(pref.getString(Preferences.SMS_PREF_SOUND, "Silent"));
     smsVibrate = pref.getString(Preferences.SMS_PREF_SOUND, "Normal");

             //all variable remain default value verified through debugger

       NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) arg0.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (arg1.getAction().equals(ACTION)){
            if(smsOn == true){....... if checkbox is checked  smsOn still remains false 
}
```

prefenceactivity class

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity implements OnPreferenceClickListener{
public static final String PREF_SMS_ON = "PREF_SMS_ON";
public static final String VIBRATE_ON_CALL1 = "VIBRATE_ON_CALL1";
public static final String SMS_PREF_COLOR = "SMS_PREF_COLOR";
public static final String SMS_PREF_SOUND = "SMS_PREF_SOUND";
public static final String SMS_PREF_VIB = "SMS_PREF_VIB";
}
```

xml file(i will just copy one)

```
    <CheckBoxPreference 
        android:key="PREF_SMS_ON"
        android:title="SMS Notifications"
        android:summary="Turn On SMS Notifications"
        android:defaultValue="false">
    </CheckBoxPreference>
```

i dont understand what it wrong, it all looks like it should work to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are some problems in your code.
This [tutorial](http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences) is good for creating preferences.
Also, if you want to change the preferences outside the `PreferenceActivity` you should use the Editor
For example:

```
Editor e = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).edit();
e.putBoolean(Preferences."PREF_SMS_ON", true);
e.commit();
```

I hope it helps

### The reply to your comment

well, the thing is that you are using `PreferenceActivity`, which as the documentation show in [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) it is used for showing a visual style of the preferences. Also, as it is indicated [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html), "the preferences will automatically save to `SharedPreferences` as the user interacts with them". It gave me the impression that you wanted to change preferences outside the `PreferenceActivity` (which is not wrong), but you say thats not what you are wanting to do.

However, I do notice that your `PreferenceActivity` is not loading the preferences from your resource file, for that you need to add `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);` in your `onCreate`, for example. But, like I said, your preferences will only change automatically if the user interacts with this activity directly.
I hope that helps.

Comment: i am not trying to change anything outside of the preference activity, all i want is to get what it is set at and the tutorial just explains what i did so i still dont understand what is wrong. i have this set the same exact way in another test program and it works perfectly